# How do I prevent flickering when drawing to a JPanel?

Tags: java, graphics

So I have a JFrame holding a JPanel, to which I'm drawing at about 60 FPS. I've been told that "Swing is double buffered by default", but, nevertheless I'm getting massive flickering. At first, I tried modifying the Graphics object from `JPanel.getGraphics()`, but was not surprised when it flickered (to black, the background colour of the game so far), as I assumed that it was redrawing when I blanked the screen. However, then I overrode `paintComponent()`, passing the Graphics to all objects to draw with, and made it call the super version, which I assumed would solve it, but no difference.

I'm still getting the Graphics object from the same place, i.e. `JPanel.getGraphics()`, because `paintComponent()` needs a Graphics argument. Should I be getting it from some other place? If not, what else could be causing the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whoops. Looks like I should have been calling `repaint()`, not calling `paintComponent(Graphics)` directly. `repaint()` calls that as part of the double buffering process, so it shouldn't be called by hand if you want to avoid flickering.

Answer (score 4):

tried to activate double buffering manually (just to make sure)?
[setDoubleBuffered](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setDoubleBuffered%28boolean%29)

On the other hand I always used a self writen double buffering at the (overwritten) update method. [Something like that](http://www.realapplets.com/tutorial/DoubleBuffering.html)

Comment: This is a good answer, but it turns out my problem was what method I was calling in the first place. But either way, useful info, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to draw onto the JPanel, but the code below worked for me to animate a sinusoidal wave.
Using `repaint()` in the program run loop seems to hold back the flickering.

```
public class YourClass extends JPanel implements Runnable{
     private boolean running = true;
     // your code here
     public void run(){
         repaint(); // called repeatedly as along as program is running
         while (running){
             update(); // called preferably 60 times a second
             render(); // no limits set, depends on computer performance
         }
     }
     // your code here
}
```